# Как сделать MD5 uuid + pass?7

Tags: python, md5

На [narodmon.ru](https://narodmon.ru) в справочнике по REST API сказано:

> * Для доступа к данным ваших приватных датчиков вне вашей локальной сети требуется однократная авторизация (userLogon).
>
> userLogon - авторизация пользователя в проекте или его регистрация
> Параметры запроса:
>
> - login логин пользователя для авторизации, если он не указан, то возвращается текущий логин для указанного uuid;
> - hash хэш для авторизации, вычисляется по формуле с объединением строк MD5(uuid + MD5(введенный пароль)), если хэш не указан, то считается запросом на регистрацию в проекте по email/sms.
>
> curl Пример запроса REST(GET):

```
http://narodmon.ru/api/userLogon?login=MyName&hash=MD5HASH&uuid=UUID&api_key=API_KEY&lang=ru
```

делаю:

```py
import hashlib

password = 'parole'
password_bytes = password.encode('utf-8')
passmd5 = hashlib.md5(password_bytes).hexdigest()
print(passmd5)
uuid = '6666666666666666666666666'
uuidbytes = uuid.encode('utf-8')
uuidmd5 = hashlib.md5(uuidbytes).hexdigest()
print(uuidmd5)
allhash = f'{uuidmd5}{passmd5}'
uuidbytes = allhash.encode('utf-8')
allbytes = hashlib.md5(uuidbytes).hexdigest()
print(allbytes)
```

вставляю в строку для curl и получаю ошибку

как правильно сделать?

Comment: Вы вроде бы делаете 
`md5( md5(uuid) + md5(пароль) )` 
а по инструкции надо 
`md5( _uuid_ + md5(пароль) )`. Иначе говоря, в allhash суйте uuid просто, а не его хэш

Comment: @Chillie
не сработало

Comment: Если вы делаете md5(uuid), то в параметр `uuid=UUID` тоже нужно пихать этот самый md5(uuid). Если вы всё уже переделали и пихаете просто uuid без md5, то тогда в параметр `uuid=UUID` тоже нужно пихать uuid без md5. Убедитесь, что у вас везде одинаковый uuid